# Moving an object from one unique_ptr to another C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I've created 2 classes: `Crane` and `Container`. `Crane` has a private member `unique_ptr<Container> container` and a public method `load()` taking a `unique_ptr<Container>` as a parameter, like this:

```
void Crane::load(unique_ptr<Container> container)
{
    if(isUnloaded())
    {
        this->container = move(container);
    }
}
```

My goal here is to give a crane a container to hold, so other `Crane` methods can put the currently held container down in a warehouse, check its id, weight, etc.

Now, in `main()` I create 2 objects: `Crane crane;` and `unique_ptr<Container> con(new Container(1));`.

In `main()`, when I want to call `crane.load(con)`, I get this error:

> error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Container; _Dp = std::default_delete<Container>]'

I thought that this is the way when you want to change ownership of an object?  Please help.

Comment: You need to use `crane.load(std::move(con))`.

Answer (score 3):

`std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied (its copy constructor is deleted).  Allowing copies would break the uniqueness of its pointer ownership.

The `container` parameter of `load()` is taken by value, so when your code passes the `con` variable to `load()`, the compiler tries to copy-construct `container`, thus the error (which, if you read it carefully, is complaining about the deleted copy constructor).

You need to use `crane.load(std::move(con));` instead, so the compiler can move-construct `container` so ownership of the pointer is moved from `con` to `container`.

The alternative is to change `load()` to take `container` by reference instead:

```
void Crane::load(unique_ptr<Container> &container)
{
    if(isUnloaded())
    {
        this->container = move(container);
    }
}
```

That way, `crane.load(con);` will work, and take ownership *only if* `isUnloaded()` is false, otherwise ownership stays with the caller (for instance, if you wanted to then try loading the container to a different `Crane`).

Comment: @Bellum that is a separate issue that warrants a new question.